# Use Scala parser combinators to read multivalue field into list of alternate values

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

### Problem

I want to parse line like this:

```
fieldName: value1|value2 anotherFieldName: value3 valueWithoutFieldName
```

into

```
List(Some("fieldName") ~ List("value1", "value2"), Some("anotherFieldName") ~ List("value3"), None~List("valueWithoutFieldName"))
```

(Alternative field values are separated by pipe (`|`). Field name is optional. If field has no name, it should be parsed as `None` (see `valueWithoutFieldName`)

### My current (not working) solution

This is what I have so far:

```
val parser: Parser[ParsedQuery] = {
  phrase(rep(opt(fieldNameTerm) ~ (multipleValueTerm | singleValueTerm))) ^^ {
    case termSequence =>
      // operate on List[Option[String] ~ List[String]]
  }
}

val fieldNameTerm: Parser[String] = {
  ("\\w+".r <~ ":(?=\\S)".r) ^^ {
    case fieldName => fieldName
  }
}

val multipleValueTerm = rep1((singleValueTerm <~ alternativeValueTerm) | (alternativeValueTerm ~> singleValueTerm))

val alternativeValueTerm: Parser[String] = {
  // matches '|'
  ("\\|".r) ^^ {
    case token => token
  }
}

val singleValueTerm: Parser[String] = {
  // all non-whitespace characters except '|'
  ("[\\S&&[^\\|]]+".r) ^^ {
    case token => token
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, my code does not parse last possible field value (the last value after pipe) correctly and treats it as value of a new nameless field. For instance:

The following string:

```
"abc:111|222|333|444 cde:555"
```

is parsed into:

```
List((Some(abc)~List(111, 222, 333)), (None~444), (Some(cde)~555))
```

while I'd like it to be:

```
List((Some(abc)~List(111, 222, 333, 444)), (Some(cde)~555))
```

### My suspicions

I think that the problem lies in definition of `multipleValueTerm`:

```
rep1((singleValueTerm <~ alternativeValueTerm) | (alternativeValueTerm ~> singleValueTerm))
```

It's second part is probably not interpreted correctly, but I have no idea why.

Shouldn't `<~` from the first part of `multipleValueTerm` left pipe representing value separator, so that second part of this expression (`alternativeValueTerm ~> singleValueTerm`) is able to parse it successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at what's happening. We want to parse: `111|222|333|444` with `multiValueTerm`.

`111|` fits `(singleValueTerm <~ alternativeValueTerm)`. `<~` throws away the `|` and we take the `111`.

So we have `222|333|444` left.

Analog to the previous: `222|` and `333|` are taken. So we are left with `444`. But `444` does not fit either `(singleValueTerm <~ alternativeValueTerm)` or `(alternativeValueTerm ~> singleValueTerm)`. So it is not taken. That is why it will be treated as a new value without variable.

I would improve your parser this way:

```
val seperator = "|"

lazy val parser: Parser[List[(Option[String] ~ List[String])]] = rep(termParser)

lazy val termParser: Parser[(Option[String] ~ List[String])] = opt(fieldNameTerm) ~ valueParser

lazy val fieldNameTerm: Parser[String] = ("\\w+".r <~ ":(?=\\S)".r)

lazy val valueParser: Parser[List[String]] = rep1sep(singleValueTerm, seperator)

lazy val singleValueTerm: Parser[String] = ("[\\S&&[^\\|]]+".r)
```

There is no need for all this identity stuff `^^ {case x => x}`. I removed that. Then I treat single- and multi-values the same way. It is either a `List` with exactly one or more elements. `repsep` is nice for dealing with seperators.

`rep1sep(singleValueTerm, seperator)` could be equivalently expressed with 
`singlevalueTerm ~ rep(seperator ~> singlevalueTerm)`